# Merge two files searching by key and add at the end

Tags: text-processing, awk, csv

I would merge data from two files into one adding only interesting Values from column. Searching key is UID in column 3 File #1. Also it should remove/omit UID duplicates and empty lines if appear.

Also will be great to read any explanation how-to approach :)

```
FILE #1:
-----------------
SVCSTO1,dbsrv01,600507600C80012F4000000000000012
SVCSTO1,dbsrv01,600507600C80012F4000000000000014
SVCSTO1,dbsrv02,600507600C80012F40000000000001C0
SVCSTO1,dbsrv02,600507600C80012F40000000000001C1
SVCSTO1,dbsrv01,600507600C80012F40000000000001C2
SVCSTO1,winsrv01,600507600C80012F40000000000001C3

FILE #2:
-----------------
239,dbsrv01_01_T2,4398046511104,600507600C80012F40000000000001C2
240,winsrv01_03_T2,4398046511104,600507600C80012F40000000000001C3
10,dbsrv01_01_T0,0,8589934592000,600507600C80012F4000000000000014
237,dbsrv02_01_T1,4398046511104,600507600C80012F40000000000001C0
238,dbsrv02_02_T2,4398046511104,600507600C80012F40000000000001C1
8,dbsrv01_02_T0,8589934592000,600507600C80012F4000000000000012


DESIRED OUTPUT:
--------------------
SVCSTO1,dbsrv01,600507600C80012F4000000000000012,8589934592000,T0
SVCSTO1,dbsrv01,600507600C80012F4000000000000014,8589934592000,T0
SVCSTO1,dbsrv02,600507600C80012F40000000000001C0,4398046511104,T1
SVCSTO1,dbsrv02,600507600C80012F40000000000001C1,4398046511104,T2
SVCSTO1,dbsrv01,600507600C80012F40000000000001C2,4398046511104,T2
SVCSTO1,winsrv01,600507600C80012F40000000000001C3,4398046511104,T2
```

I'm able to manipulate the data output like below example but don't have experience how to build a array or merge multiple outputs into one :(

```
# for i in `cat file1.log | awk -F"," '{print $3}'` ; do cat file2.log | grep $i | awk -F"," '{print $3/1024^3" GB"}'; done
8000 GB
...
```

Comment: your command tries to add suffix `GB` - it contradicts with your `DESIRED OUTPUT:` . Why?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest
It's only example of data output manipulation. But, I also would use awk to convert Bytes to other units in output file.

Answer (score 0):

This `sed` one does only convert your input to the given output. You may expand it for your needs:

```
sed -E '/^[0-9]/{s/.*_(.*)(,.*),(.*)/\3\2,\1/;H;d;};G;s/,(.*)\n.*\n\1(,[0-9]*,T[0-9]*).*/\1\2/' file2 file1
```

The idea for such a task is always the same: First read the second file to build up a lookup table in the hold space, then append this lookup table to each line of the main file.

In detail:

- the pattern `/^[0-9]/` addresses lines starting with a number, so everything inside the `{}` is executed for `file2` only
- `s/.*_(.*)(,.*),(.*)/\3\2,\1/` extracts just the parts we need from the second file, already in the desired order
- `H;d` appends this to the lookup table in the hold space and throws that line away. Other processing is for `file1` only
- `G` appends the lookup table and `s/,(.*)\n.*\n\1(,[0-9]*,T[0-9]*).*/\1\2/` does find the key (between `,` and newline) as backreference `\1` in the lookup table to append the fields from the table

Comment: Nice work man! You're SED guru :) working nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Also found other way to solve this via AWK and is working for me.

```
awk -F"," 'FNR==NR{a[$4]=$3 FS $2;next}{ print $0","a[$3]}' file1 file2
```